# How to make a list of items in a view and add it in a list to a product all in ones

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a suplier and he has an order. I would like to select a product in a view and add a list of items to that product.

I can send them 1 by 1 but,
but how to add them in all in ones, i cant figure it out.

What is the best way to do this, forward it in json?
In what html form?
Can anyone help me, I'm not getting out of it.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it through jQuery. Make an Array in jQuery function and pass list Item in that array on each Click Event. When you append your all List Items in List then pass it to the Controller either Ajax Request or from Razor View Form in Json Format.